# C# Razor - ViewModel returning empty to the controller

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core

I have a view that receives a list from a ViewModel. When this list is inside an @if {} block it returns empty to the controller. When the list is outside the @if {} block it returns all items to the controller. What could be happening? I'm using .Net core 2.2. Thanks!

```
 @model List<Project.DataAccess.ViewModels.Values.ValuesVM> 

<form form asp-controller="Values" asp-action="ValuesIndex" method="post">

   @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @if (Model[i].Tipo == 1)
        {
            <div class="flex-column">
                <div class="flex-row">
                    <div style="text-align:center; width:200px;">
                        <span class="grid-margin-text">@Model[i].Name</span>
                    </div>

                    <div  style="text-align:center; width:50px; background-color:aliceblue;">
                        <span class="grid-margin-text">@Model[i].Value1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:50px;">
                        <input asp-for="@Model[i].Value2" value="@Model[i].Value2"
                               id="iptDC@(Model[i].Guid)" type="number" style="width:50px; text-align:center;" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        }   
    }
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: place a field of the list, which will not be changed (edited), outside the "ifs".

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
     <div style="display:none;">
        <input asp-for="@Model[i].Id" value="@Model[i].Id"
               id="iptId@(Model[i].Guid)" type="number" />
     </div>

    if block 

}
```